# Spring property configuration

Tags: spring

I have read up dozens of articles on Spring but could not find an elegant solution to this problem.

a) Load a properties file using **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**. E.g.

```
// Load properties file
@Bean(name = "appProperties")
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getApplicationProperties() {
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("app.properties"));
return bean;
}
```

b) Find the database type configured in "app.properties"
app.database=mysql

c) Then load properties related to this database type using **PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer** (E.g. mysql.properties) and make it available in the Context for beans

Comment: Hi @Romail, Please look into this : http://kruders.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-using-annotation/

Comment: This link does not help. I want to load a new properties file based on a property defined in app.properties

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
      PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
      ClassPathResource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ]
        { new ClassPathResource( "db.properties" ) };
      ppc.setLocations( resources );
      ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
      return ppc;
    }

    @Value( "${jdbc.url}" ) private String jdbcUrl;
    @Value( "${jdbc.driverClassName}" ) private String driverClassName;
    @Value( "${jdbc.username}" ) private String username;
    @Value( "${jdbc.password}" ) private String password;

    @Bean(name="datasource")
    public DataSource datasource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }
```

I think above may be helpful

Create `db.properties` that contains your database details

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

Comment: This does not help. I want the location "db.properties" to be changed dynamically based on property defined in app.properties. So for e.g. if in app.properties I have "app.database=mysql", then I want to load "mysql.properties". If I have "app.database=h2" then I want to load "h2.properties"

Answer (score -1):

Just try with this.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = "name of package where you are writing the class" )
@PropertySource({ "classpath:(properties file name).properties"})

@Configuration
public class RootAppConfig {


  @Bean
  public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

this is using spring 4.0+

and just use `${property name}` where ever required